# I need a triple Integration setup to this problem

Tags: integration, volume

Write an iterated triple integral in the order dzdydx for the volume of the region bounded
below by the xy-plane and above by the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$ and lying inside the
cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = 4$?

how can I solve this problem I already have the final answer but I don't know how to solve it, the answer to this problem is $(V=8(π-1/3)$
I tried solving it  with this:

$\int_{-2}^2\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_0^{x^2+y^2}dzdydx = 8π$

but it didn't work

Comment: Could you edit your question to show what that integral gives instead?

Comment: did it ..............

Comment: The integral seems correct to me. Possibly you made some mistake in calculation? (And sometimes errors happen in "final answers", too..!)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer: could you show the steps that get you another answer?

Comment: I have made sure that I haven't made any mistakes in the calculation, But yea maybe the final answer is wrong but I'm not sure

Comment: J.G I put the integral into an online integral calculator, so we don't need to rewrite all of it, and it's 100% true don't worry